# How to insert a variable in a file name in bash?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, scripting

I am currently learning bash and learned some basics.

Now that I want a variable name for a file (e.g 'Backup_2020-04-24') it does not work.

I should also mention that I'm on a MacOS device

What it looks like:

`variable = "test"
tar -zcvf projects_${variable}.gzip testfolder`

expected: gzip file with name projects_test in a folder named testfolder.

The gzip gets created in the test folder, however.. the name is 'projects_'.

Does anyone know why this is the case and can explain it to me? when echoing, the variable is not empty.

Excuse me if this post is formatted bad, this is my first post in here. Please don't hesitate to tell me what do do better next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the spaces around `variable = "test"`. Try `variable=test` instead? (This should really be a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet to comment).

Or if the value you want `variable` to take on is something that needs to be computed:

```sh
foo=$(date --date='@2147483647')
echo $foo
#> Mon Jan 18 19:14:07 PST 2038
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That indeed helped with the variable that was a simple string, but my actual variable is like this and as soon as I remove the space after the '=', it says command not found. I do get the date when I echo it, however it is not showing up in the filename.: 

DATE= date -v -1d +%Y%m%d

it basically returns yesterdays date

Comment: So set `DATE=$(date -v -1d...)`

Comment: The idea is that you can't have spaces between the variable name, the equal sign, and the variable value.

Comment: You made my day! thanks a lot! Could you please explain why this is the case?
Where can I read more about this? I admit I am a little bit confused on the '$()' part.

Comment: I don't know nearly enough about bash, if I'm being honest, but... `$()` starts a new shell I believe, and runs whatever command, returning the stdout of that command. So when you have `foo=$(...)`, that starts a new shell, runs the stuff, then sets `foo` to whatever that stuff returned.